# Rails build JSON object from hash and arrays via model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am trying to post data to an API, **the API is requesting a JSON request as this**:

```
{
    "blacklists": {
        "list1": [{
            "id": "123",
            "find": "foo",
            "type": "text"
        }],
        "list2": [{
            "id": "321",
            "find": "bar",
            "type": "text"
        }]
    }
}
```

My problem is building a JSON with hash and arrays representing the above.

**This is the code I have so far:**

```
@blacklist = {}
@bl = {}

key_category = KeywordCategory.where("global_list = ? OR unit_id = ?",1,1)

key_category.each do |kc|

bl_name = kc.name # <- "list1, list2 etc."

kc.keywords.each do |kw|
 @keywords = {}
 @keywords['id'] = kw.id
 @keywords['find'] = kw.data
 @keywords['type'] = kw.is_regexp ? "regexp" : "text"
 @bl.merge!(@keywords)
end

end

@blacklist['blacklist'] = @bl

return @blacklist.to_json
```

**This code gives me this JSON (which is a bit from the one the API wants):**

```
{
"blacklists":
{"id":123,
"find":"foo",
"type":"text"
}
}
```

How do I change my code so it spits out according to the top JSON?

Comment: can't understand what you have and what you need, clarify please

Comment: I need to get a JSON string, exactly as the one I have provided. Trying to achieve that I have written the code below, but the problem is that it does not create a string as the above, also keys gets duplicated.

Comment: describe, what you doing in your code, associations, etc. More detail. Not in comments, just edit question

Comment: ok, I have edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
@blacklist = {}
@bl = {}

key_category = KeywordCategory.where("global_list = ? OR unit_id = ?",1,1)

key_category.each do |kc|

  tmparray = []

  kc.keywords.each do |kw|
   @keyword = { id: kw.id, find: kw.data, type: kw.is_regexp ? 'regexp' : 'text" }
   tmparray << @keyword
  end
   @bl.merge!(kc.name: tmparray)    
end

@blacklist['blacklist'] = @bl

return @blacklist.to_json
```

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot!!!
Just a question from a ruby noob, what does `tmparray << @keyword`do with the array?

Comment: `<<` method appends argument to array. Check out this doc page http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Array.html#method-i-3C-3C